# Why include QtWidgets for a command line application?

Tags: c++, qt, console, widget

I have create a simple Qt console app (based on an example code provided by Qt).  Although this is a console app, ldd shows lots of X11 stuff linked in.

I noticed in my .pro file I have `QT += widgets`. That seems strange for a console app, so I removed widgets but not compiling shows:

```
main.cpp:13:24: error: QApplication: No such file or directory
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:26: error: ‘QApplication’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:26: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘app’
main.cpp:47: error: ‘app’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:21: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
main.cpp:21: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Can someone tell me what's going on?  Should I need widgets for a console app?  And if not, why can't I remove it succesfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`QApplication`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html) is part of the QtWidgets module in Qt 5, so if you want to use that, well, you need to include it.

If you don't need any GUI stuff at all, use [`QCoreApplication`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html) instead. It's in the QtCore module and doesn't require including the fancy graphics parts.